# Integrate express js API in React for data visualization with canvasJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, canvas

I have created an api in node.js which gives me some data in json. I want to use this data for visualization. I have comeup with an example on data visualization using canvasjs in React.

```
class BarChart extends Component {
    addSymbols(e){
        var suffixes = ["", "K", "M", "B"];
        var order = Math.max(Math.floor(Math.log(e.value) / Math.log(1000)), 0);
        if(order > suffixes.length - 1)
            order = suffixes.length - 1;
        var suffix = suffixes[order];
        return CanvasJS.formatNumber(e.value / Math.pow(1000, order)) + suffix;
    }
    render() {
        const options = {
            animationEnabled: true,
            theme: "light2",
            title:{
                text: "Most Popular Social Networking Sites"
            },
            axisX: {
                title: "Social Network",
                reversed: true,
            },
            axisY: {
                title: "Monthly Active Users",
                labelFormatter: this.addSymbols
            },
            data: [{
                type: "bar",
                dataPoints: [
                    { y:  2200000000, label: "Facebook" },
                    { y:  1800000000, label: "YouTube" },
                    { y:  800000000, label: "Instagram" },
                    { y:  563000000, label: "Qzone" },
                    { y:  376000000, label: "Weibo" },
                    { y:  336000000, label: "Twitter" },
                    { y:  330000000, label: "Reddit" }
                ]
            }]
        }

        return (
        <div>
            <h1>React Bar Chart</h1>
            <CanvasJSChart options = {options} 
                /* onRef={ref => this.chart = ref} */
            />
            {/*You can get reference to the chart instance as shown above using onRef. This allows 
you to access all chart properties and methods*/}
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default BarChart;
```

Here all the data are in static form. But i would like to fetch the api and visualize according to data available. P.S.:: If anywould suggest me something other than CanvasJS for data visualization except for d3. That would be great as well. Any help or any article would really be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [CanvasJS React gallery](https://canvasjs.com/react-charts/json-data-api-ajax-chart/) for a demo on rendering chart with data being read from JSON.